# Setting a list item is converting it into a tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Firstly, I'm sure this is just something pythonic that I'm unaware of. However, I've been baffled for ages so I need some help!

```
v = ['']*8 #create a list of 8 empty strings
data = ['N','S','E','W','NW','NE','SW','SE'] #create some data
for i in range(0,len(v)-1): #go through each data item
    v[i] = data[i], #copy each data item into the same place in v
```

Now as far as I see this *should* give me `v=['N','S',`...etc. However it is giving me `v=[('N',),('S',)`...etc which is most confusing!

(Note: I *know* this isn't the right way of doing this exercise in and of itself, there is madness in my method)

**Update:** The original posting had the last line: `v[i] = data[i]` (no comma) which confused everyone, because essentially the code worked. Now that we see `v[i] = data[i],` the symptoms are clear.

Comment: `for i in range(0,v-1)`?  `v` is a list - what is the result of `list-1` ? This ain't the code you're running - also `v` is a list of 8 strings ... not 10 so even your comments do not match

Comment: This code [doesn't even run](https://ideone.com/eCaSIK), please make a [mcve]

Comment: One usually uses `v = data[:]`.  (btw upon fixing `v-1` to `len(v)`, your code seems to work - with no sign of any `tuple`s)

Comment: `len(v)` still [doesn't create a tuple](https://ideone.com/OFGT89), please make a [mcve]

Comment: @quamrana I'm aware of the v=data[:] - I'm trying to do something very specific and silly. Thanks though - the len(v) missing was a mistake. I have solved the problem and added the answer, I wasn't aware a rogue comma could make so much difference.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted as, try as I might I could not reproduce.

The reason I couldn't reproduce was there was a typo in the original in which `v[i]=data[i],` had a rogue comma.